# Cut an image view using points that are drawn by using touches

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.

I know crop an image using CGRect value and masking .But now i want to create an app in that i will draw some shape using touches and drawRect method on a imageview  and now i want to get only the part of an image within that shape only means i want to crop the original image into that shape. Is it possible to do.Do anyone have an idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Calculate the rectangular bounds of the shape.

2- Extract a cropped sub-image of that size (or a couple of pixels over, depending on the app's intent).

Then you have some choices:

a- You can change every pixel outside of the shape to white (or white, or blue, or whatever)
b- You can set every pixel outside of the shape to transparent

3- Save it.

If you are really industrious you can even apply some dithering to the edge to smooth it out.

Comment: Thanks for your response Martin. Yes i am also trying in that way only by croping the original image into sub image by calculating the minx,maxx,miny,maxy values. But after that i struck to find the values outside that boundary.

Comment: Martin can you put the code over here i can't understand what you want to say.